# How to remove space between keyboard and comment box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can't remove the space between the comment box and the keyboard.

Please see the below image for the issue

[image: issue image]

and below is my code

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 48,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: SizedBox(
                width: 90,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [

                      const SizedBox(width: 40),
                      RichText(
                          text: const TextSpan(children: [
                        WidgetSpan(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.send_outlined,
                                color: AppColors.appColor0,
                              )),
                        )
                      ])),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Please tell me what mistake I am doing. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same case as you, i did it by calculate new bottom inset.

First you must set your `Scaffold` attribute to `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`

Then calculate new buttom inset for the textfield. Default bottom padding is 48, so calculate only if bottom inset is larger than bottom padding to ensure the padding is always positive number:

```
double getBottomInsets() {
   if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom >
       MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom) {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom -
             MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Don't need to `setState` just apply the padding for your FAB widget and it automatically adjust the inset:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
floatingActionButton: Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    bottom: getBottomInsets(),
  ),
  child: YourTextField(),
),
```

Finally the keyboard and FAB close-fit!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved that with SingleChildScrollView in the body

```dart
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          reverse: true,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: mq.height * 0.8,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Obx(
                  () => ListView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: _c.list.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final message = _c.list[index];
                      return MessageCard(message: message);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _c.textC.text = "Tolong catat ";
                      _isFirstTap = true;
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Tolong catat"),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _c.textC.text = "Bantu diingat ";
                      _isFirstTap = true;
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Bantu diingat"),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _c.textC.text = "Hitunglah ";
                      _isFirstTap = true;
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Hitunglah "),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _c.textC.text = " ?";
                      _isFirstTap = true;
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("?"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _c.textC,
                    focusNode: _textFocusNode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    onTap: () {
                      if (_isFirstTap) {
                        _isFirstTap = false;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: "...",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  radius: 25,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.send_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 28,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _c.askQuestion();
                      _isFirstTap = true;
                      _c.textC.text = "";
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

hope that's will help

Answer (score -1):

You should set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` and dynamically add your padding based on is keyboad open or not. Something like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isKeyboardOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: isKeyboardOpen
            ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
            : const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 48,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: SizedBox(
                width: 90,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      // Image.asset("assets/images/home_icon/mic.png"),
                      const SizedBox(width: 40),
                      RichText(
                          text: const TextSpan(children: [
                        WidgetSpan(
                          child: SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.send_outlined,
                              )),
                        )
                      ])),
                      // Image.asset("assets/images/home_icon/send.png"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              prefixIcon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
                child: RichText(
                    text: const TextSpan(children: [
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.photo_camera_outlined,
                        )),
                  )
                ])),
              ),
              hintText: 'Add comments...',
              // hintStyle: NewStyles.textValueGreyR14,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 0),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                // borderSide: const BorderSide(color: AppColors.appColor2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                // borderSide:
                //     const BorderSide(color: ApplicationColors.chatBGcolorEE),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried this but it hides the text box!

Comment: Yes, that's what resizeToAvoidBottomInset does by itself when it's set to true, so if you set it to false you need to add your bottom insets for your text box by yourself.

Comment: I understand, let me try.